# Como trocar a cor do ícone no drawable layout no android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Olá, estou precisando trocar a cor do ícone q aciona o menu do DrawableLayout, porem não estou achando a propriedade ou onde posso personalizar esse ícone.

Como eu troco a cor desse ícone?
Aonde eu coloco a cor dele?
Qual elemento?
Qual nome do arquivo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mudar a cor do ícone hamburguer você deve abrir o arquivo **style.xml**

E então nessa classe, adicione a linha responsável pela cor:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    /*linha responsável pela cor abaixo*/
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    /*linha responsável pela cor acima*/
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Depois basta alterar a cor na linha `<item name="color">@android:color/black</item>`

---

Respondendo ao **Woton Sampaio**:

O esquema é o mesmo, porém para trocar a cor dos 3 pontinhos, você deve adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

Qualquer dúvida com a implementação nos avise.

Abraços

Comment: Cara, não sou o dono da pergunta n kkkk, mas vc sabe como altera os 3 pontinhos do menu tb?

Comment: Se puder colocar junto da sua reposta agradeço

Comment: Já deixei meu +1

Comment: Woton Sampaio, fiz uma edição na minha resposta com a alteração que você precisa para mudar a cor dos 3 pontinhos

Comment: Muito obrigado, vlw

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado